# What is antiJARLocking attribute?

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, tomcat

what does the attribute `antiJARLocking` mean ? What is it's significance when I turn it to *true / false* ?

I have seen this attribute in `context.xml` file of web-application :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context antiJARLocking="true" path="/poll">
 <Resource name="jdbc/PollDatasource" auth="Container"
           type="javax.sql.DataSource"
 // etc etc
</context>
```

Comment: See related Question, [Why shouldn't i turn on “antiJARLocking” in production environment?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/22480442/642706) with [Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22482267/642706) by Tomcat expert [Mark Thomas](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1299005/mark-thomas).

Answer (score 33, accepted):

## Tomcat 7

From the [Tomcat 7.0 documentation for Context Configuration](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/context.html):

> *"antiJARLocking - If true, the Tomcat classloader will take extra measures to avoid JAR file locking when resources are accessed inside JARs through URLs. This will impact startup time of applications, but could prove to be useful on platforms or configurations where file locking can occur. If not specified, the default value is false."*

(The problem they are trying to address … I think … is that a locked JAR file will stop things like hot redeployment from working.)

Read the documentation for more information.

## Tomcat 8 and later

The `antiJARLocking` attribute is replaced by the [`antiResourceLocking`](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-8.0-doc/config/context.html#Standard_Implementation) attribute in Tomcat 8 and later.   The documentation mentions some noteworthy side-effects of setting this attribute.

---

See also:

- http://stackoverflow.com/q/22480442/642706 ... which notes that turning on this feature may be enabling a permgen (or in Java 8+ a metaspace) memory leak if you perform hot redeploys.

Answer (score 8):

Windows likes to lock files during classloading, thus preventing them from being manually deleted or being opened by another application. It also causes problems when undeploying and redeploying a war. In Tomcat, when you specify `<Context antiJARLocking="true"/>` this will prevent Windows from acquiring a lock on your jars